# Finding a and b in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find $a$ and $b$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}-11\\9\\-12\end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\3\end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix}7\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}$

I think it's trivial that $a = -4$, which is what I have found to be correct. Is there a method to figure out what $b = ?$ without the exhaustive trial and error? Or is that the whole point of this problem?

Comment: Yes, you find $a=-4$ by looking at the 3rd coordinate. Having done that you can find $b=-1$ equally quickly by looking at the first coordinate.

Comment: $9=(-4)(-3)+b\times 3$ . Whats $b$?

Comment: In general you may convert the conditions into a matrix equation and row reduce to find the answers.

Comment: Really, the $-1$ downvote? For what reason does this deserve a downvote? This is a honest question. I'm sorry I wasn't born with innate knowledge of all math tricks known to man

Comment: Ahh, had a brainfart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\3\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}7\\3\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-11\\9\\-12\end{bmatrix}$ can be rewritten in the following form:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&7\\-3&3\\3&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-11\\9\\-12\end{bmatrix}$

Using Gaussian Elimination and row reduction, one can solve the following for $a$ and $b$ (*or find that no solutions exist*)

To do so, form the augmented matrix by concatenating the matrix on the far left with the matrix on the right side of the equation and [row reducing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Row_Reduction_and_Echelon_Forms) it.

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&7&-11\\-3&3&9\\3&0&-12\end{array}\right]$

After row reduction, this [becomes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1,7,-11%7D,%7B-3,3,9%7D,%7B3,0,-12%7D%7D)

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&0&-4\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\end{array}\right]$

Interpreting the results, this implies that $a=-4$ and $b=-1$ and that $0=0$.

---

As an aside, if the final line had been something like $[0~0~|~1]$ that would have been interpreted as $0a+0b=1$, i.e. that $0=1$, which we know to be false.  If our work implied something false were true, that would imply that there was in fact no solution to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You must have 
$$b\begin{bmatrix}7\\3\\0 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}-11\\9\\-12 \end{bmatrix}+4\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -7\\ -3\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 2):

from the last line we get $$a=-4$$ and the second one we get $$9=12+3b$$ from here we have $$b=-1$$ and plugging this in the first line we have: $$-11=-4-7$$ and this is true.